# jCarousel load content with ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I made a jCarousel on my home page with all the feature products, but if the feature products are 100 in number the home page will load very slowly so I decided I will load the content with ajax, I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 with razor view engine. This is my actually code:

```
            <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
                $(window).load(function () {
                    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                        jQuery('#sidebarcarousel').jcarousel({ scroll: 1 });
                    });
                });//]]>  
            </script>

              <ul id="sidebarcarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
            @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
            {
                <li>
                    <div class="item-box">
                        @Html.Partial("_ProductSmallBox", item)
                    </div>
                </li>    
            }
            </ul>
```

and using css to show the carousel correctly. I don't know how to make an ajax call to load the content.

Comment: Is not so simple - this ajax call must been supported directly by your carousel javascript library.

Comment: That means is not possible ?

Comment: "Everything is possible" - if this is your library http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ I found an example here http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax.html  so you can probably do it.